# Physical path of localhost During VS 2008 Debug

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Where is the physical path of the aspx files from which the webpage is served? I am pressing F5 in my VS 2008, and I want to know where VS stores my aspx files during the debugging process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just hooks up a local web server to your application directory - files aren't being stored elsewhere.

Comment: This can depend on the startup settings of VS, check the project properties to confirm (e.g. using a remote server would serve content from a remote location).